# Unity (C#) random numbers are created in batches

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm creating 500 random numbers in a Unity project like so:

```
int[] random_numbers = new int[500];
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) 
{
    random_numbers[i] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(60, 100);
}
```

The results I get are the numbers seem to be created in batches. For example, I will get the number 89 ten times in a row and then the number 95 ten times in a row and so on. I don't have a problem with getting the same number, but I can't have them created in large batches like this.

I understand that the Unity random number engine uses the clock to create the number. I'm wondering how I can get better quality random numbers?

Comment: Should be random. Maybe you print them using `Debug.Log` and have "Collapse" enabled in Console by accident?

Comment: You are calling the constructor very rapidly and getting same number because the clock is being used to seed the generator.  You need to call the constructor only once and then use next.  See following : Random rand = new Random();
            rand.Next(60,100)

Comment: @jdweng no that is wrong. UnityEngine.Random.Range is a static function, that is [statically initialized](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html). You may be talking about System.Random, but that wouldn't make a difference either in randomness. (Only in memory maybe)

Comment: @KYL3R : It is what is happening.  I've seen problem before.  When you get the same number multiple times you are calling the constructor with the same timestamp and getting the same random number.

Comment: Try adding `int x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(60, 100);` and then setting your array value to be x

Answer (score 1):

Numbers should be random. Make sure to have "Collapse" disabled in the console:

[image]

[image]

Or save it in a **public** or **[Serialized]** field and view it in the Inspector.

Comment: I have the numbers saved in a database. I can see that my first 100 numbers were all 96.

Comment: I'm sure the error is not in Random.Range. Maybe you used the wrong index. Please show more code (where you write to database)